# Unable to save sheet with Xlwings - "Another user is working on the document"

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to save an excel sheet with Xlwings that have macros in it and when i run the code, or try to save the sheet manually, i get the this error.

"Another User' is working on the document, try again later"

I can only save the file when i terminate the code. I want to save the file without needing to rename it, because i have other files formulas connected with this sheet.

Anyone have an idea?

I updated my xlwings to 0.29.0 and tried the context manager as follow.

```
with xl.App(visible=True) as app:
wb = xl.Book(arquivo)
wb.save()
```

and got the following error:

> com_error Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
> 1 with xl.App(visible=True) as app:
> 2     wb = xl.Book(arquivo)
> ----> 3     wb.save()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py in save(self, path,
> password)    1145             path = utils.fspath(path)    1146
> with self.app.properties(display_alerts=False):
> -> 1147             self.impl.save(path, password=password)    1148     1149     @property
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py in save(self,
> path, password)
> 823         if (saved_path != "") and (path is None):
> 824             # Previously saved: Save under existing name
> --> 825             self.xl.Save()
> 826         elif (
> 827             (saved_path != "") and (path is not None) and (os.path.split(path)[0] == "")
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py in **call**(self,
> *args, **kwargs)
> 107         while True:
> 108             try:
> --> 109                 v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
> 110                 if isinstance(v, (CDispatch, CoClassBaseClass, DispatchBaseClass)):
> 111                     return COMRetryObjectWrapper(v)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in Save(self)
>
> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exceção.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'O método
> Save da classe Workbook falhou', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284),
> None)

Comment: Do you have zombie excel processes running?

Comment: How do i see that? If i have It, light né something with my code...

Comment: Use Task Manager to see if there are multiple instances of Excel running that you haven't started by opening Excel. Since Xlwings opens 1 or more instances of Excel when it runs if the code fails to execute properly and aborts it's possible the Excel instance is not closed properly and 1 or more zombie Excel processes remain. One of which could be holding your workbook open and subsequently preventing you from saving.

Comment: There's just one Excel instance when i run the code. I don't know if it helps, but when i try to "wb.close()", the Excel window remains open without any information.

Comment: You may want to use a context manager to ensure all opened Excel instances are closed when your code ends. However it doesn't appear as though the file is locked by another instance of Excel.

Comment: When i try the context manager "with xw.App(visible=False) as app:" i get the "__enter___" AttributeError. Any ideia why? I'm just trying to open the file and save it any chances.